# How to stop Mobile chrome from discarding/reloading tabs?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have been listening to some old radio shows on an archive website (radioechos) on my phone but if I pause what I am listening to and leave my phone for too long then when I return the tab has refreshed and I have lost my place in the show

I have managed to find many ways to stop chrome from doing such things on desktop but none for mobile chrome (chrome://discards/ does not appear to exist for mobile)

Comment: Try opening the website in Desktop mode and check if it still reloads.